# How does a black hole's gravity affect other dimensions?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime-dimensions

Given the extreme gravitational force of a black hole, can it have affects on other higher dimensions?  Does it continue to warp space-time regardless of the number of dimensions?

In fact, can a black hole have enough affect on the space of another dimension that the line between one dimension and another becomes blurry and one dimension can become another?

Comment: Nobody has seen any other dimensions, yet, even though we have tried hard to find them. Take a look at "compact extra dimensions" and "non-Newtonian gravity".